# pointers in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have following situation. My aim is to make a and b such that both of them points to same memory. But the condition is that both of them are pointers. How do i do it?

```
struct myStruct
{
struct anotherStruct* anoStrct;
};
main()
{
   struct myStruct *a=( struct myStruct*)malloc(sizeof( struct myStruct));
   struct myStruct *b=( struct myStruct*)malloc(sizeof( struct myStruct));
   a=b;


}
```

Comment: In your code, the memory zone which you first `malloc` (the original `a`)  is lost so is a memory leak. Use a memory leak detector (e.g. `valgrind` on Linux) and your debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could allocate space for one pointer for example, `a` as

```
struct myStruct *a= malloc(sizeof( struct myStruct));
```

and assign this pointer to `b` as

```
struct myStruct *b = a;
```

**EDIT:** When you copy pointers and use them for some operations, you also would have to be careful w.r.t. copying i.e. whether the copy is a shallow-copy or deep-copy. Please do refer to [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) for more details.

In the aforementioned code segment, if the following statements are executed after initializing `b` with `a`, you will encounter a segmentation fault as the original pointer has already been freed.

```
free(b);
a->anoStrct = malloc(sizeof(struct anotherStruct));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast malloc, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @chrisw69 Thanks.. I just copied the statement from the question. I was in the middle of editing when my system crashed :)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct myStruct *a=malloc(sizeof(*a));
struct myStruct *b=a;
```

Note that since `a` and `b` both point to the same memory, updates to one will (obviously) also affect the other.  Also, you must only later call `free` on one of the pointers.

Your suggested code also leaves both variables pointing to the same memory.  It leaks the memory that was originally allocated for `a` however.

Comment: Thanks buddy..Maybe its due to 4AM and i am half asleep, i asked this stupid question...you woke up me.:-)

Comment: @simonc **originally allocated for b** is not rite. originally allocated to `a` is lost